# Extract OTP from message and show only OTP value in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a string let's say : `Rishav app OTP is : 1232`

I also have the regex : `/^\b\d{ 4}\b/`

Somehow when I test and match the regex with the string it shows me false.
But when I test the regex online it highlights the OTP.

Can someone please help me with the code of getting only the OTP number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using anchor wrongly, `^` this means start of string so it tries to match pattern from start of string whereas your **OTP** you're searching for not always suppose to be at start of string, so just drop `^`

```js
let str = "Rishav app OTP is : 1232"

console.log(/\b\d{4}\b/.test(str))
```

If your OTP is always at end of string than you should use `$` which means end of string , i.e

```
\b\d{4}$
```

> How can i get number, OTP will always be the first digit in string

```js
let str = "Rishav app OTP is : 1232"
let str2 = "4561 is the One Time Password for logging into Application /iasdas2123"

let getOTP = (str) => {
  let match = str.match(/\b\d{4}\b/)
  return match && match[0]
}

console.log(getOTP(str))
console.log(getOTP(str2))
```

Comment: It's returning true, but how to get the value of OTP?

Comment: @RishavKumar some quick question, 1) will OTP is the only number you string can have or there can be any other number in string, 2) will the OTP always appear after `:`

Comment: Answering 1 : Nope, it would have some other numbers also but it is sure the other numbers would be after the OTP Value.  2: `4561 is the One Time Password for logging into Application /iasdas2123.`

Comment: `4561 is the One Time Password for logging into Application /iasdas2123.` This is the final string. I want to get the number in first occurence

Comment: @RishavKumar updated answer with how to get OTP from string